# oAuth authentication in unit tests using django rest framework and django oauth toolkit

Tags: django, unit-testing, oauth, django-rest-framework

How do I write unit tests for those endpoints of my API that require oAuth authentication?

Simply adding oAuth tokens to the request headers doesn't work (perhaps because the test database is not persistent). Loading fixtures into the database doesn't help either.

I am using django-rest-framework together with django-oauth-toolkit.

My test.py code:

```
class Com_jm_Test(TestCase):
    fixtures=['oauth.json',]
    print 'test com jm'
    multi_db=True

    def test_list_job(self):
        self.client=Client(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Bearer 0cx2G9gKm4XZdK8BFxoWy7AE025tvq')
        response=self.client.get('/com-jm/jobs/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code,200)
```

The result:

```
AssertionError: 401 != 200
```

Answer (score 8):

Do it this way:

1. Create user
2. Create application
3. Create token

```py
...
    def __create_authorization_header(token):
        return "Bearer {0}".format(token)

    def __create_token(self, user):

        app = Application.objects.create(
            client_type=Application.CLIENT_CONFIDENTIAL,
            authorization_grant_type=Application.GRANT_AUTHORIZATION_CODE,
            redirect_uris='https://www.none.com/oauth2/callback',
            name='dummy',
            user=user
        )
        access_token = AccessToken.objects.create(
            user=user,
            scope='read write',
            expires=timezone.now() + timedelta(seconds=300),
            token='secret-access-token-key',
            application=self.app
        )
        return access_token

    user = User(username='dummy', email='dummy@geneu.com')
    user.save()
    self.user = user
    token = __create_authorization_header(__create_token(user))
    response=self.client.get('/com-jm/jobs/', format='json', HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=token)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code,200)
```

Of course, this must be adapted to your needs, but this is the idea. For future problems of this kind  (when you didn't find enough information in the documentation for archiving your goals) I recommend you to check out the source code. In this case for example you can find how to do this in the test of the toolkit lib. ([django-oauth-toolkit/oauth2_provider/tests/test_authorization_code.py](https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit/blob/master/oauth2_provider/tests/test_authorization_code.py))

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same problem. Here is my solution.

**DRF provides `APIClient` for making requests.**

The `APIClient` class supports the same request interface as Django's standard Client class. This means that the standard `.get(), .post(), .put(), .patch(), .delete(), .head()` and `.options()` methods are all available.

Also provides The `credentials` method can be used to set headers that will then be included on all subsequent requests by the test client.

```
client = APIClient()
client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token AB7JSH^4454')
```

[DRF docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#apiclient)

**Creating Oauth Token**

create and get user

```
token = user.oauth2_provider_accesstoken.create(expires='expire_date', token='token')
```

Setting Ouath token with APIClient

```
client = APIClient()
client.credentials(Authorization='Bearer {}'.format(token))
client.get(reverse('accounts_api:profile'))
```

We can set the Default content type

```
REST_FRAMEWORK += {
    'TEST_REQUEST_DEFAULT_FORMAT': 'json'
}
```

[Git Hub Link for Source](https://gist.github.com/deepakkabbur/edb150eb812f49e6c6341c0fac4eee83)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look a DRF's documentation on testing, specifically [the chapter on "Forcing authentication"](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#forcing-authentication). From those docs:

> For example, when forcibly authenticating using a token, you might do something like the following:
>
> ```
> user = User.objects.get(username='olivia')
> request = factory.get('/accounts/django-superstars/')
> force_authenticate(request, user=user, token=user.token)
> ```

Comment: I have tried that before,but when I put queryset of user into the testcase,it always gives me a error massage of cannot find the data meet the queryset

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? What queryset are you using? And have you  loaded test user data in the test database?

Comment: it seems that something wrong with the fixture_dirs,i am trying to fix that,is there any other ways to test without forcing authentiaction?Cause the purpose I do the unit test is to show that only the request with token can access to my API,thanks a lot

Comment: If you want to test whether the view is inaccessible to unauthorized users, just test for a `HTTP 401 Unauthorized` response. `self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 401` will do the job. Ofcourse you should also be testing whether authorized users can access the view which takes us back to your original question :)

Answer (score 0):

Depend on your application you may want to patch this function from django-oauth-toolkit to return arbitrary access token for your client:

```
oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication.authenticate
```

Since this is the method used for authentication in django-rest-framework by default.

Answer (score 0):

This is a refinement combining the answers from @Deepak Kabbur and @Daniel Albarral.

1. Derive a subclass of DRF's **APIClient** to set up the credentials using an OAuth2 application belonging to a given user:

   ```
   import rest_framework.test
   from oauth2_provider.models import Application, AccessToken

   class APIClient(rest_framework.test.APIClient):
       def credentials(self, user: User, application_name: str):
           # Create or update OAuth2 application.
           app, created = Application.objects.update_or_create(
               defaults={'name': application_name},
               client_type=Application.CLIENT_CONFIDENTIAL,
               authorization_grant_type=Application.GRANT_AUTHORIZATION_CODE,
               redirect_uris='https://www.none.com/oauth2/callback',
               name=application_name,
               user=user)
           # Create or update the token, and set it in a default request header.
           now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
           access_token, created = AccessToken.objects.update_or_create(
               defaults={'user': user, 'application': app},
               user=user,
               scope='read write',
               expires=now + datetime.timedelta(seconds=300),
               token='secret-access-token-key',
               application=app)
           super().credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Bearer {}'.format(access_token))
   ```
2. Create test cases using the derived APIClient (you have to use at least **APITestCase** since the process for setting up the credentials requires database access):

   ```
    class TestAPI(rest_framework.test.APITestCase):
        client_class = APIClient

        def test_000_authenticate(self):
            self.client.credentials(ACME_MASTER_ADMIN, 'my-app')
            response = self.client.get('/api/v1/company'), format='json')
            assert response.status_code == 200
   ```